# Freeing 2D arrays in C. "double free or corruption" and "invalid next size"

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management, malloc, free

So I am having a memory problem using gcc.

I have this 2D array inside a struct. I am trying to make this C code a little bit easier for myself with Object-Oriented programming.

What seems to be the problem here. Whenever I try to free_Foo, I run into "Error in `./Foo': double free or corruption (out): 0x0000000001713050 ***

```
typedef struct {
    char** map;
    int height;
    int width;
} Foo;

Foo* init_Foo(int width, int height){
    Foo* f = (Foo*) malloc (sizeof(*f));

    char** map;
    map = (char**) malloc (height* sizeof(**map));
    int i;  
    for ( i = 0; i < height; i++){
        map[i] = (char*) malloc(width * sizeof(*map));  
    }

    f->map = map;
    f->height = height;
    f->width = width;

    return f;
}


void free_Foo(Foo* f){
    int i;  
    for ( i = 0; i < f->height; i++){
        free(f->map[i]);
    }
    free(f->map);
    free(f);
}
```

Comment: The `malloc` call for `map` should also just be `sizeof(*map)`, i.e. only one indirection. The per-row `malloc` should use two levels.

Answer (score 1):

Change this statement

```
map = (char**) malloc (height* sizeof(**map));
```

to

```
map = (char**) malloc (height* sizeof( *map));
```

And correspondingly this statement

```
for ( i = 0; i < height; i++){
    map[i] = (char*) malloc(width * sizeof(*map));  
}
```

to

```
for ( i = 0; i < height; i++){
    map[i] = (char*) malloc(width * sizeof(**map));  
}
```

Expression `**map` has type `char` while `*map` has type `char *`

So you could write instead

```
map = (char**) malloc (height* sizeof( char * )); // *map

for ( i = 0; i < height; i++){
    map[i] = (char*) malloc(width * sizeof( char ));   // **map
}
```